# Const non-reference parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, constants

Does the following usage of const have any value?

```
void Func(const bool state) {
    std::cout << "The state is: " << state << std::endl;
}
```

`const` references are certainly recommended and I surely see the benefit of it. But, coming to simple `const` addition to non-reference parameter. Is that of any use?

Comment: If you put `state = false;` in the body (intentionally or mistakenly), the compiler will error.  That can be valuable if it was indeed a mistake.

Comment: Yes. I know that but my question was more towards - "Is it a good programming practice". But looking that the other associated discussion, it sounds like not. I got my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These function declarations

```
void Func(const bool state);
```

and

```
void Func(bool state);
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

You even may include the both declarations in a compilatfion units.

However if the parameter is declared with the qualifier const then inside the function definition it may not be changed.

Pay attention to that parameters of a function are its local variables.